# page redirect to index page in url rewrite using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi i am new to url rewrite so please help in this bug

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)  chanel.php?user=$1 [L]
```

my above code shown about my .htaccess file .

my orginal url is`www.abcd.com/chanel.php?user=ravi`

i want to rewrit above url to `www.abcd.com/ravi`
but above .htaccess file redirect to index.php

so pleae help me in above bug

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ chanel.php?user=$1
```

This won't allow punctuation, just the alphabet and digits.